# how to list col1 with the multiple values in col2

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I need to to know

- are there multiple Product-ID for the same barcode number
- are there multiple barcodes number for the same Product-ID

example of the dataset:

````
data = {'Proudct':['SLL', 'MNO', 'Drin', 'JAJ'],
        'Product-ID':[20, 20, 19, 18]
         'barcode':['3633', '7676', '2313','3311'}
 df = pd.DataFrame(data) ``` 


I need the output to be like:

Name   ID   Code
SLL    20    3633
MNO    20    7676
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform('count')`:

```
filtered = df[df.groupby('Product-ID')['barcode'].transform('count') > 1]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
  Proudct  Product-ID barcode
0     SLL          20    3633
1     MNO          20    7676
```

Comment: if there is different name that has the same id but has different code , is it still working?

Comment: I just want to list the IDs that has more than multiple codes, not all the codes.

Comment: Check the answer now.

Comment: it just show the duplicates ids and code. not working

Comment: Then will you please update your expected output in the question? This code (and mozway's) shows what the question says you want, so if you want something different, you'll need to clarify that.

Comment: Please check the Question now.

Comment: @Pythona check my answer now. Hopefully it's what you're looking for...

Comment: it is working in this data set. but it is not when i use it in my real data set. i have other columns , do you think it has effect?

Comment: No matter how many columns you have, this should still work. :)

Comment: I think I just found what is the problem. The code return repeated and unique codes as long as the product-id has more than one barcode . I just want to return a unique barcode if they have more than one unique barcode. Can you help me?

Comment: @Pythona please ask a full, new question...this is getting a bit messy :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) method that is specifically made for this:

```
df[df[['Name','ID']].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Output:

```
  Name  ID  Code
0  Tom  20  3633
1  Tom  20  7676
```

Comment: no. i want to see if Id takes more than one code. this solution will generate the duplicate code and id.

Comment: please check the Question now